# String class for gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I want a string class in gcc, like in Visual studio

Comment: This question is scaring on several levels.

Comment: Last I checked, VS didn't have any classes?

Answer (score 7):

Use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

If you *really* need it, there are `CString` [workalikes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/stdstring.aspx?msg=864083) out there.  But you really should use `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which string class you used in Visual Studio, still the usual [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) is standard C++ and is available in any standard-conforming C++ implementation (including g++ as well as Microsoft Visual C++).